# mysql_fetch_assoc not fetching data

Tags: php, mysql

When I run my php file it outputs:

> ERROR: Could not fetch results,

I do not understand why though, I used this exact code in other files and it works fine.

Code:

```
<?php
$mysql = mysql_connect('localhost','root','password') or die('ERROR: Could not connect, ' . mysql_error($mysql));
mysql_select_db('twp',$mysql) or die('ERROR: Could not connect, ' . mysql_error($mysql));
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM DenCrypt_Users",$mysql) or die('ERROR: Could not lookup users, ' . mysql_error($mysql));
if(!$q)
{
    die('ERROR: Could not lookup users, ' . mysql_error($mysql));
}
while($row[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
{
    $lp[] = $row['lastPing'];
    $usr[] = $row['usr'];
    for($i = 0; $i < count($usr);$i++)
    {
        if($lp[$i] + 180 >= time())
        {
            $q = mysql_query("UPDATE DenCrypt_Users SET online='Offline' WHERE usr='$usr[$i]'") or die('ERROR: Failed to update user, ' . mysql_error($mysql));
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I have ran the same query on phpmyadmin and it works. Why isn't php fetching the data?

Comment: What does `mysql_error()` say?

Comment: Please, don't use mysql_* functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, here is [good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: @peterm: re "*begun the deprecation process*", it is in fact [now deprecated as of v5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php).

Comment: mysql_error() says nothing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One *expects* [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) to eventually return false, at the end of the resultset.  Don't die on this eventuality, just exit the loop:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
{
  // etc.
```

However, as others have mentioned, you *really* should stop using the now-deprecated `ext/mysql`.  Switching to the *improved* [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) extension is almost as simple as inserting the letter `i` into each function call, although one also ought to invest in [parameterising prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/623041) in order to mitigate against SQL injection attacks.

Comment: I originally had no die statement, I added in hope of finding a problem. I forgot to revert back to original code. It doesn't modify the db nor does it display anything.

Comment: @PatrickThomas: remove the `[]` after `$row`, as shown in my answer above.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're adding a new item to the Array `$row` in each iteration of the while loop.

```
while($row[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($q) or die('ERROR: Could not fetch results, ' . mysql_error($mysql)))
{
    $lp[] = $row['lastPing'];
..
}
```

I think you shouldn't be able to access an item with the index `lastPing` on the Array `$row`. Do you intend to collect the fetched rows in an array like that? If not, just use

```
while ( ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) !== false ) { .. }
```

Note the missing square brackets after `$row`. (die removed as stated by eggyal)